# FaceTime continually drops and loses net connection

Tags: facetime

Comcast high-speed internet; up-to-date Apple devices. I'm never able to complete a conversation: FaceTime freezes, modem loses Internet connection.

Every.Single.Time.

Comment: Modem? Do you mean the Comcast router?

Comment: It happened during so many days? is iMessages working fine?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a specific channel on your router and pointing your AirPort connection to the same channel (rather than leaving it on automatic, which looks around and sometimes drops connections whilst doing so).